# How to test recursive function in Jest.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, testing, jestjs

I have an script to looping over directories and match files with specific type. Unfortunately jest passes this test before it ends. I know why, but I don't know how to make script to wait for the end of looping.

```
import fs from 'fs'
const path = require('path');

describe('something', () => {
    it('should something', () => {
        const traverseDir = (dir, callback) => {
            fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
                let fullPath = path.join(dir, file);
                if (fs.lstatSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
                    callback(fullPath)
                    traverseDir(fullPath, callback);
                } else {
                    callback(fullPath)
                }
            });
        }

        traverseDir('src/', (fullPath) => {
            const splitted = fullPath.split('/')
            const filename = splitted[splitted.length - 1]
            if (filename.match(/.*.foo/)) {
                fs.readFile(fullPath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
                    expect(err).toBe(null)
                    // some assertion
                })
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Have you read about testing asynchronous code in Jest?  https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass `done` in the test parameter and call it when the test ends.

You can read more about async testing [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous).

```
import fs from "fs";
const path = require("path");

describe("something", () => {
  it("should something", done => {
    const traverseDir = (dir, callback) => {
      fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
        let fullPath = path.join(dir, file);
        if (fs.lstatSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
          callback(fullPath);
          traverseDir(fullPath, callback);
        } else {
          callback(fullPath);
        }
      });

         done(); // Call done to tell Jest that the test has finished.
    };

    traverseDir("src/", fullPath => {
      const splitted = fullPath.split("/");
      const filename = splitted[splitted.length - 1];
      if (filename.match(/.*.foo/)) {
        fs.readFile(fullPath, "utf8", (err, data) => {
          expect(err).toBe(null);
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: It won't work always because assertions also are called recursivly and done may be called many times. For example it can firstly call done and next find the file which fail a test

Comment: Then you can call it after the foreach loop.

Comment: This is the basic idea to test the async functions.

Comment: I have updated the answer, could you please try this .

Comment: Ok i fixed it by wrapping it on promises. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use `fs.promises` functions to list the contents of your directory recursively to obtain a single unified file list.

**Unit test this function separately** from any code that actually reads the file.  (e.g.:  your `filename.match` and `readFile` code should be tested separately from the `traverseDir` code.)

#### Example of walking directories asynchronously to get a unified file list:

This asynchronous `allFilesIn` function gets all files within a directory recursively and returns the list as a single array with full (relative) paths.

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

const allFilesIn = async (dir, results = []) => {
  const files = await fs.readdir(dir);
  for (file of files) {
    const fullPath = path.join(dir, file);
    const stat = await fs.stat(fullPath);
    if (stat.isDirectory()) {
      await allFilesIn(fullPath, results);
    } else {
      results.push(fullPath);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

// Example call:
allFilesIn('src/').then(files => {
  console.log(files); // e.g.:  [ 'src\\foo.cpp', 'src\\bar.cpp', 'src\\include\\foo.h' ]
});
```

Once you have a single array of all the files it should be easy to use a single `forEach` to do something for all the files in the unified list.